# test records for rails development database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Seems like one of the strengths of the test database is that it can quickly reload fixtures before each test. Is there something similar for the development database in rails? Seems like it could make it easier to be able to load test fixtures into it to have some data to review? I'm sure this question has been asked before but I wasn't able to find an answer to it. I also know that ultimately I should be doing most of the interface testing thru the tests but as a newbie that is sometimes a challenge by itself.

Any tips or solutions that people might offer would be greatly appreciated!

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rake db:fixtures:load
```

will load fixtures in to the database for the current Rails environment